# PHP elseif issue

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to add col-lg-6 to one of the Divs when no content is being displayed for name3 and name4, but it keeps showing as col-lg-4.

```
<?php
$name3 = get_field('name3', $post->ID);
$name4 = get_field('name4', $post->ID);
?>

<div class="col-lg-3">
    <!-- name1 exists -->
</div>

<?php if ($name3 == "" || $name4 == ""): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <?php elseif ($name3 == "" && $name4 == ""): ?>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- name2 exists -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <!-- name3 does not exist -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <!-- name4 does not exist -->
        </div>
```

I've looked on here and other sites but I just can't figure it out. I know it's probably going to be something stupid and simple but I really need to sort this out now.

Comment: Switch your statements. If either one is empty, it's always going to hit the first `if`. You want to check to make sure both is empty, *then* if only 1 is empty.

Comment: Have you used var_dump on the $name3 and $name4 variables to see if they contain the proper stuff you're checking for/against?

Comment: Thanks aynber, you're a star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply reverse order of checks:

```
// if both are empty
<?php if($name3 == "" && $name4 == ""): ?>
<div class="col-lg-6">
// if one of them is empty
<?php elseif($name3 == "" || $name4 == ""): ?>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<?php else: ?>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<?php endif; ?>
```

otherwise first if () is true when one of variables is empty **and** if both are empty

also you can just change || (or) operator to xor operator in your first if ()

Answer (score 0):

Currently when your second `if` could be valid, it goes anyway to the first one. To resolve it, swap their order.

Change :

```
<?php if($name3 == "" || $name4 == ""): ?>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<?php elseif($name3 == "" && $name4 == ""): ?>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<?php else: ?>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<?php endif; ?>
```

To :

```
<?php if($name3 == "" && $name4 == ""): ?>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<?php elseif($name3 == "" || $name4 == ""): ?>
<div class="col-lg-6">
<?php else: ?>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<?php endif; ?>
```